# JSF and browser back

Tags: ajax, jsf, browser

I have a very strict requirement to use POST to pass in request parameters to my application upon entry.  Once entering the application (page1), entering form information and continuing to the next page (page2) via a commandButton, the expectation is that the data will be posted and later read from a session scoped manage bean.  All works well except when using browser back on page2 to navigate back to page1.

I have tried adding a redirect tag on the navigation rule that navigates from page1 to page2 to no avail.  I have also tried this implementation of the Post-Get-Redirect pattern (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html).  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate back? and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting that the values on page1 persist after I redirect to page2 and then use browser back to get back to page1.  Right now, all of the values are missing.

Comment: What is the scope of the bean that you are using for Page1? If the scope is "Request", then don't expect to retain the values in the form when you redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Abel, the scope of page1 is request.

The solution we came up with which is no means ideal is to disable browser caching on the previous page.  What this means is that whenever you refresh the page using the browser refresh button or click the browser back button, the browser will indicate that the page is expired and prompt a warning asking whether you want to re-submit the request.

We do have a work around which is to provide navigation buttons within the webpage but the idea was to support browser back.  This would be easy using GET parameters, but POST provides additional complexity which we have decided to mitigate by by providing our in-house navigation buttons.